# Splunk - How to generate a "identity column" id 1,2,3,

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

We're logging info/error logs in Splunk/db. We're using .net and nlog.

In db, we're getting it in the right order when sorting because of identity column.

In Splunk, it's coming out of order if many log entries have the same date.

Is there a chance to tell Splunk to create a "identity column" for everything that is piped into it?
We're piping the logs into Splunk using HTTP Event Collector.

We're using Splunk Enterprise.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a sample of a log event and indicated whether this "identity" column is expected to be from the data in the log event, or simply some magic sequence (from the ingest time or dateTime of the log event).

Comment: And you should edit your question to add the info "We're using Splunk Enterprise." What you posted is not an answer.

Comment: I was thinking if Splunk can generate a number (in ascending order) that I can use to order from, when my date is not enough to filter data.
like | sort -Date,-thisIdImTalkingAbout

Comment: Splunk is time-based so time is how Splunk sequences events.  The order of events with the exact same time is not preserved.  There is no built-in feature akin to an 'identity column'.  Using something like `INGEST_EVAL` requires some persistent, ever-increasing value, for which the current time is the best option, but then you're back where you started.

Comment: Is there a chance that 2x log entries will have the same time stamp? If so, how do you order them correctly?

Comment: Yes, it's possible for more than 1 event to have the same timestamp.  This happens all the time when data comes from multiple sources, but can happen with a single source, too.  Splunk doesn't order such events as they appear to happen at the same time so order is moot.  It's up to the user to impose an order based on the content of the events.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using "|streamstats count | the rest of your search here...|" as a means to create a new column with an increasing counter.  Reference this link:  https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.2.2/SearchReference/Streamstats  and scroll down to the first example under "Usage".